# Overwrite wordpress page with new content

Tags: wordpress, import

I have created a new page and template that I would like to overwrite the old page, but keep that page the same since I have multiple pages linking to the page. To be a bit clearer:

1. I have a page called product-1 (Post ID: 1)
2. I have a page called product-1-test with all new content and post-meta (Post ID: 2)
3. I want all the content on product-1-test to be imported and overwrite all content on product-1

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to override the contents in WP editor of overide the co rent in frontend?

Comment: why cant you do it manually

Comment: Just swap the slugs.